# How can I JSON serialize a queryset on Django?

Tags: json, ajax, django

I'd like to return on my ajax response a queryset, this is the error I get when I try to serialize a queryset.

> TypeError: 'Font: FontName' is not JSON serializable

I am using JSON response like so :

```
...
return JsonResponse({
    'foo': Font.objects.filter(id=1).first(),
})
```

---

I also tried, same error :

```
response = json.dumps({
    'foo' : tmp_fonts,
})

return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

---

**third try :**

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

```
# tmp_fonts = [<Font:CaviarDream>, <Font:Arial>, <Font:Calibri>, etc...]

return JsonResponse({
    'foo': serializers.serialize('json', tmp_fonts),
})
```

I'd like to be able to get it back on response and display every fields in the query on my template. Is this even possible ?

---

**Model :**

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    font = models.ManyToManyField(Font)

class Font(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/). If it is not enough, you can always crate a manual dict with what you need. ALso, you have to use `JsonResponse`, throw away the second one.

Comment: Can you post your serializer and model both. Also in your third try what is `tmp_backgrounds`

Comment: Inside the serializer, replace `tmp_fonts` with `Font.objects.all()` (or whatever it is). It is supossed to work with a QuerySet, not a list.

Comment: Adding to @RompePC comment I would suggest create a serializer to serialize the objects of your model.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki +1

Comment: I see you're still using filter().first(), instead of get() :)

Comment: @Melvyn I write my code differently on StackOverflow in order to be understandable by everyone, then I readapt and use get() in my django apps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the short version is:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Font


class FontListAjaxView(generic.View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse(data=list(Font.objects.values()), safe=False)
        # or the "safe" version, where data needs to be dictionary:
        # return JsonResponse(data={'data': list(Font.objects.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :** That is what worked for querysets in list.

```
# tmp_fonts = [<Font:CaviarDream>, <Font:Arial>, <Font:Calibri>, etc...]

response = JsonResponse({
    'foo' : serializers.serialize('json', tmp_fonts),
})

return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: You can forget the HttpResponse. Just return the JsonResponse. A JSonResponse is a HttpResponse with the right content type, that accepts it's input as a dictionairy that it turns into Json, using JSONEncoder. So it's still a HttpResponse.